# What is wrong in this Shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I keep getting unary operator expected. It seems PRC is not being assigned the value.

```
PRC=`ps -ef | grep test | wc -l`
if [ ${PRC} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Congrats"
```

Comment: Well, did you check the contents of `PRC`? Also, you should quote it within `[]`: `[ "$prc" -eq 1 ]`.

Comment: if i run this `echo PRC=`ps -ef | grep test | wc -l`  i get PRC=1 and the first line throws an error like command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `ps -ef | grep test` will usually include the `grep` process in the output, which you probably don't want. A "clever trick" to avoid this is to match for the string "test" with a regular expression *that is not the simple string "test"*:

```
$ ps -ef | grep test
jackman  27787 24572  0 09:53 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto test
$ ps -ef | grep test | wc -l
1
```

versus

```
$ ps -ef | grep '[t]est'
(no output)
$ ps -ef | grep '[t]est' | wc -l
0
```

I do this often enough that I wrote this bash function `psg` (for "ps grep"):

```
psg () { 
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER     # no arguments? vanity search
    for arg do
        patterns+=("-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}")
    done
    ps -ef | grep "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

---

You could also just use

```
pgrep -f test
```

Comment: Great minds think alike! +1 for making a function out of often-used functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget your closing `"fi"`:

```
PRC=`ps -ef | grep test| wc -l`
if [ "${PRC}" -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Congrats"
fi
```

You didn't mention what shell, but this works in bash.

Save a process by using the -c (count) option to grep:

```
PRC=`ps -ef | grep -c test`
```

Be advised your pipeline includes in the count the grep command itself, so as you mentioned in your comment above your count is most likely misleading as it is only counting itself.  Instead, use this:

```
 PRC=`ps -ef | grep -c [t]est`
```

This will match commands with "test" in them but not the grep command itself.  This is because this is using a regular expression that matches a word starting with a "t".  Your command starts with a square bracket so it won't match itself.  Resist doing a "grep test | grep -v grep" which is sloppy and just unnecessarily uses a process.